# Proper way to update an arrow dataset in R

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I would like to know if there is a good practice to update an `arrow` dataset. Imagine I have data that I first write as follow:

```r
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressMessages(library(arrow))

td <- tempdir()

head(mtcars)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Create an arrow dataset with a partitioning based on `cyl`:

```r
write_dataset(mtcars, td, partitioning = "cyl")
```

We can see that there are 3 folders, one for each `cyl`.

```r
dir(td)
#> [1] "cyl=4" "cyl=6" "cyl=8"
```

Now, lets open the dataset and filter to only keep `cyl == 6` and re-write it to the same folder:

```r
open_dataset(td) |>
  filter(cyl == 6) |>
  write_dataset(td, partitioning = "cyl")
```

There are still 3 sub-folders:

```r
dir(td)
#> [1] "cyl=4" "cyl=6" "cyl=8"
```

All the original data is still there because re-writing `cyl == 6` did not remove `cyl == 4` and `cyl == 8`:

```r
open_dataset(td) |>
  distinct(cyl) |>
  collect()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>     cyl
#>   <int>
#> 1     6
#> 2     4
#> 3     8
```

My question is how one would proceed to update an existing dataset?

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "update". For one understanding of "update", that's what you did: you overwrote the `cyl=6` values and didn't touch any others.

`write_dataset()` has an `existing_data_behavior` argument that governs this. Default is to overwrite individual files, but you can have it `"error"` if partition dirs already exist, or `"delete_matching"` would in this example delete `cyl=6/*` and write new files for that partition.

See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/write_dataset.html for details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my example, I was looking to delete everything that is not cyl == 6. I guess would have to delete the "main" directory first and re-write with the new data.

Comment: That sounds right. For good measure, you might also want to use `existing_data_behavior = "error"` so that the write fails if you happen not to delete the directory first instead of silently doing the partial update.